# HTACCESS with HTTPS and subdomain with port

Tags: .htaccess

I have spent few hours to find a answers for a simple question, but I didn't. With htaccess on apache server, I want:

1-All traffic to be HTTPS

`http://example.com` >> `https://example.com`

(edit) AND ALSO

2-All traffic to a subdomain to be redirected to a specific port

`subdom.example.com` >> `subdom.example.com:1234`

I have created this piece of crap, but doesn't work in all the cases

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^subdom.example.com$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^1234$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}:1234%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# If not https, then force it
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Finally, nice to have would be to always redirect example.com to www.example.com

Thank you all for your support

Comment: https ://subdom. example.com is not redirecting to https ://subdom. example.com:1234 Sorry for the space, but don't know how to avoid the auto-link

Comment: thanks @anubhava, I have not been able to understand the htaccess background. I see this as a runable script that runes from top to bottom... But not sure. Anyway, even when the first rule should already redirect, I guess there is something wrong somewhere because it does not redirect as expected.

Comment: Can you show  ViftualHost config of your subdomain in question

Comment: Well, all this is behind a synology nas, so I am not used to the console, nor the file structure, so don't have an idea how to get the info you ask for. If you believe the htaccess syntax is correct and the issue could be in the VirtualHost please confirm and I will spend all needed time to find the config of VirtualHost in my nas

Comment: Yes your rules look fine as as I commented earlier should redirect from `http://subdom.example.com/` to `https://subdom.example.com:1234/`

Comment: Yes, that works fine, but what I want is to always use https, and in case of subdom, then add port 1234. In the case httpS: //subdom.example.com/ it doesn't include the port 1234 at the end

Comment: But there is already a `https` in `https://subdom.example.com:1234/`

Comment: I might be not clear in my explanation, thanks for your patience. In case `https://subdom.example.com/` without port, I do not get `https://subdom.example.com:1234/` redirection with the port